# Elevating apps rights on a mac

Tags: objective-c, elevated-privileges

I am writing an app that requires writing to system protected folders like the /Applications. How to do that properly? Tried this code, but that doesn't seem to work on an account without Admin rights (prompt for the password appears).

```
AuthorizationRef authorizationRef = NULL;

AuthorizationItem authItem      = { "", 0, NULL, 0 };
AuthorizationRights authRights  = { 1, &authItem };
AuthorizationFlags flags        =   kAuthorizationFlagDefaults              |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed    |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize          |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

OSStatus status = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, &authorizationRef);
status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authorizationRef, &authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, NULL);

if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
    Logger::logErrorF("Unable to elevate permissions");

Poco::File file("/Applications/Test");
file.createDirectory();

AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef, flags);
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to create any helper tools for that, just want to elevate rights when necessary, do what I want and lower rights afterwards.

Also what's the best way to determine if the currently running process has admin rights?

Comment: You are doing it properly. There is no supported mechanism for elevating a process without prompting for admin credentials. This is a security feature. By default even an admin-level process *does not* start with admin rights.

Comment: It prompts for an admin password, that's ok. But when I try to create a folder under "/Library/Application Support/Test" I get permissions error. So the question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need a helper - the authorization only applies to applications launched with the `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` call. It doesn't affect the currently running process.

Comment: Been wandering how does the Battle.net client do it? It asks for the password as startup and does not install any helper, as far as I know. http://dist.blizzard.com/downloads/bna-installers/322d5bb9ae0318de3d4cde7641c96425/beta.3/Battle.net-Beta-Setup-enGB.zip

Comment: It asks for elevation when it detects that it's not running with EUID 0, If this operation fails, then you get the 'something went wrong' screen; If you give it authorization it re-executes itself as elevated.

Comment: Allright, will try the 'uid_t uid=getuid(), euid=geteuid();' and try to re-run the same process with elevated rights. Thanks!